# is it possible to create a 3D polyline over a QML Map?

Tags: qt, qml, qtlocation

I am trying to plot the flight trajectory of an airplane using QML maps.

```
 Map {
            [...]
            MapPolyline {

                [...]
                path: [
                    { latitude: ..., longitude: ..., altitude: 0},
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    { latitude: ..., longitude: ..., altitude: 10000 }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately the plotted line is flat (2D) and does not show the change in elevation.

**Is it possible to plot a polyline over QML maps in 3D  ?**

Comment: not available out of the box

Comment: Hi @Pa_ would you know about any addendums that would make what I want to do possible ?

Comment: not to the best of my knowledge. I think it's possible, but it needs to be implemented. And also, what would you expect to see? a 3d thin line extrusion? shaded? Polylines in QtLocation are, as of today, two-dimensional and unshaded.